# How would I remap a dead key such as a comma?

Tags: autohotkey

I'm wanting to remap my dvorak keyboard to the following. The comma is supposed to be a dead key. How would you do this in autohotkey?

[image: 1]

Answer (score 3):

You can map any key to do nothing by mapping it to `return`

```
,::return
```